Update temp table with a column related to two other tables
I'm working with a stored procedure to create a temp table for reporting.
I have a temp table for reporting vehicle operation with these column:

Report (Order_number, ID_Car, ID_Operation, Travel_Distance, Month, Year, ID_Require, Name_Equipment)

and those table about vehicle operation

Car_Info (ID_Car)
Operation (ID_Operation, ID_Car, Travel_Distance, Month, Year)
Require_Content (ID_Require, ID_Car, Month, Year)
Require_Detail (ID_Require, Name_Equipment)

Car_Info table



ID_Car




Truck


Scooter


Van



Operation table for report travel distance of vehicel monthly



ID_Operation
ID_Car
Travel_Distance
Month
Year




1
Scooter
100
1
2024


2
Truck
150
1
2024


3
Van
200
1
2024


4
Scooter
123
2
2024


5
Truck
456
2
2024


6
Van
789
2
2024



Require_Overview table to display general information about proposed repairs



ID_Require
ID_Car
Month
Year




R1
Truck
1
2024


R2
Van
1
2024



Require_Detail table to dispaly detailed information about proposed repairs



ID_Require
Name_Equipment




R1
roof


R1
windscreen


R2
hood


R2
headlight


R2
wheel



Here is the result of temp table I want to output:



Order_Number
ID_Car
Travel_Distance
Month
Year
ID_Require
Name_Equipment




1
Scooter
100
1
2024




2
Truck
150
1
2024
R1
roof








windscreen


3
Van
200
1
2024
R2
hood








headlight








wheel



Here is a query that creates and inserts values in the Report table:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MONTH_REPORT]
    @MONTH as SMALLINT,
    @YEAR as SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [#Report]
    (
        [Order_Number] [int] NULL,
        [ID_Car] [int] NULL,
        [ID_Operation] [int] NULL,
        [Travel_Distance] NUMERIC(9,0) NULL,
        [Month] [smallint] NULL,
        [Year] [smallint] NULL,
        [ID_Require] [int] NULL,
        [Name_Equipment] [nvarchar](100) NULL 
    )

    INSERT INTO #Report(Order_Number, ID_Car)
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.ID_Car) AS Order_Number,
            A.ID_Car
        FROM 
            Car_Info A

    UPDATE #Report 
    SET ID_Operation = Operation.ID_Operation,
        Travel_Distance = Operation.Travel_Distance,
        Month = Operation.Month,
        Year = Operation.Year
    FROM #Report, Operation
    WHERE #Report.ID_Car = Operation.ID_Car 
      AND @Month = Operation.Month 
      AND @Year = Operation.@Year
        
    UPDATE #Report 
    SET ID_Require = Require_Overview.ID_Require
    FROM #Report, Require_overview
    WHERE #Report.ID_Car = Require_overview.ID_Car 
      AND Require_Overview.Month = @Month 
      AND Require_Overview.Year = @Year

    UPDATE #Report 
    SET Name_Equipment = Require_Detail.Name_Equipment
    FROM #Report, Require_Detail
    WHERE #Report.ID_Require = Require_Detail.ID_Require

    SELECT * FROM Report

--MONTH_REPORT '1', '2024'

When I run procedure MONTH_REPORT '1','2024' I get this result:



Order_Number
ID_Car
Travel_Distance
Month
Year
ID_Require
Name_Equipment




1
Scooter
100
1
2024




2
Truck
150
1
2024
R1
roof


3
Van
200
1
2024
R2
hood



How can I do it right? I am stuck when updating Name_Equipment for the Report table.

Please show us the results you are expecting.

FYI: 1) Comma joins are not current best practice. Use explicit joins. 2) Why are you doing so many updates? Why not join everything you need on and do a single update?

Aside... you're already specifying target column names in INSERT INTO #Report(Order_Number, ID_Car) so it's redundant to use AS Order_Number in the select.

I shortened UPDATE with table Operation, but still confuse when insert value for Name_Equipment. When I use INSERT INTO #Repost(Name_Equipment)
SELECT Require_Detail.Name_Equipment FROM #Report
JOIN Require_Detail ON Require_Detail.ID_Require = #Report , it will add 5 rows name equipment below Repost table but the value in new rows is NULL.

You need to [edit] your question to clarify what the issue is.

Based on your given table structure your code has some mistakes.
Your CREATE TABLE [#Report] statement need to be
 CREATE TABLE [#Report]
(
    [Order_Number] [int] NULL,
    [ID_Car] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    --[ID_Car] [int] NULL,

    [ID_Operation] [int] NULL,
    [Travel_Distance] NUMERIC(9,0) NULL,
    [Month] [smallint] NULL,
    [Year] [smallint] NULL,
    [ID_Require] [nchar](10) NULL,
    --[ID_Require] [int] NULL,
    [Name_Equipment] [nvarchar](100) NULL 
)

ID_Car and ID_Require cant be int.
Also first Updtae #Report statement has parameter mistake. It needs to be
 UPDATE #Report 
SET ID_Operation = Operation.ID_Operation,
    Travel_Distance = Operation.Travel_Distance,
    Month = Operation.Month,
    Year = Operation.Year
FROM #Report, Operation
WHERE #Report.ID_Car = Operation.ID_Car 
  AND @Month = Operation.Month 
  AND @Year = Operation.Year

Operation.@Year usage is not correct.
My solution for you is as follows.
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MONTH_REPORT_MOD]
  @MONTH as SMALLINT,
  @YEAR as SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [#Report]
    (
        [Order_Number] [int] NULL,
        [ID_Car] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        --[ID_Car] [int] NULL,

        [ID_Operation] [int] NULL,
        [Travel_Distance] NUMERIC(9,0) NULL,
        [Month] [smallint] NULL,
        [Year] [smallint] NULL,
        [ID_Require] [nchar](10) NULL,
        --[ID_Require] [int] NULL,
        [Name_Equipment] [nvarchar](100) NULL 
    )

    INSERT INTO #Report(Order_Number, ID_Car)
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.ID_Car) AS Order_Number,
            A.ID_Car
        FROM 
            Car_Info A

    SELECT c.Order_Number, c.ID_Car,o.Travel_Distance, o.Month,o.Year,
            ISNULL(r.ID_Require,'') ID_Require, 
            ISNULL(d.Name_Equipment,'') Name_Equipment

    FROM #Report c
    LEFT JOIN Require_Overview r on c.ID_Car=r.ID_Car
    LEFT JOIN Operation o on c.ID_Car=o.ID_Car
    FULL OUTER JOIN Require_Detail d on d.ID_Require=r.ID_Require

    WHERE o.Month=@MONTH and o.Year=@YEAR
   
    DROP TABLE [#Report]

END

I modified the original procedure with _MOD addtion to name.
Running procedure as
exec [MONTH_REPORT_MOD] '1', '2024'

gives the result

It is the result set you are looking.
